# How to get the output from NodeJS when use the child_process.spawn to launch a bat on windows OS, and the bat will open a new terminal

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, shell, command-line

**If the bat only run one terminal ,we can got the stdout, but we will failded if this open a new window.**

```
    var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('aa.bat');
    console.log('Starting..terminal.pid.', terminal.pid, "process.pid", process.pid);
    terminal.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stdout:',data);
    });
    terminal.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stderr:',data);
    });
    terminal.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
        console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
    });
    terminal.on('exit', function(code) {
        console.log('exit code:', code, ' terinal.pid.', terminal.pid, "process.pid", process.pid);
        console.log('child process', process.pid, 'exited with code ' + code);
    });
```

**presumed the bat file like this**

```
start  cmd
```

if we change it to

```
start /b cmd
```

this will not open a new terminal ,the nodeJs will work

Comment: so why do you need it opened in a new terminal? it's a batch file, just run it in the same process and monitor that.

Comment: the batch file is out of my control, I just need invoke this file and get the output from nodeJS. I have found a way to solve this,but need to integrate a bash.exe on windows

Comment: No it's not. If you can call the .bat file for execution, you can also load the file and change its content so it doesn't branch out.

Comment: Yes, I hope it's a bat file, it's an exe actually, it's an exe open an new process. I just use the bat to emulate the enviroment. I think that it's the only way to import the bash in windows, Thank you all the same.

Comment: you may want to change your post, then, and answer it yourself so that others in a similar situation can do the same, or request the question is removed because it turned out to not be what you thought.

Comment: Please don't do this ... somewhere a maintenance programmer is weeping over something like this ...

Comment: I have answered, maybe it's not the best solution, but it's a way to deal with this problem

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to get another process stdout from NodeJS on windows os, at most time it open an new terminal window. but you can use an bash to launch it.

1.The bash.exe you can download from http://www.steve.org.uk/Software/bash/
then the code maybe like this:

```
    var terminal = require('child_process');
    function start() {
            if (process.platform.trim() !== 'win32') {
                terminal = terminal.spawn('bash');
                console.log('This is not the win32 plantform ,please confirm the bash woking!');
            } else {
                terminal = terminal.spawn('./bash-2.03/bash.exe');
            }
            // !!!must append the ./
            //terminal.stdin.write('./aa.exe');
            terminal.stdin.write('./aa.bat');
            terminal.stdin.end();
        };
        start();
        terminal.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data + "");
        });
        terminal.stdout.on('error', function(data) {
            console.log('error:\n' + data);
        });
        terminal.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
            console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
        });
        terminal.on('exit', function(code) {
            console.log('exit code:', code, ' terinal.pid.', terminal.pid, "process.pid", process.pid);
            console.log('child process', process.pid, 'exited with code ' + code);
        });
```